# Calling C/C++ method in C#

Tags: c#, c++, c

Suppose you have a library **my_library.dll** with following methods declared in it:

```
int method_1(char *param1, unsigned long *param2, bool param3)
int method_2(char *param1, unsigned long *param2, bool param3, bool &param4, long &param5, char[1024] param6)
```

and you need to call them in C#. To call **method_1**, I can do this:

```
[DllImport("my_library.dll", EntryPoint = "method_1")]
static extern int mapped_method_1(string param1, UInt32 param2, byte param3)
```

and the **mapped_method_1** can be called as regular C# method.

Can somebody help me to do this for **method_2**?
I am struggling how to map the "&" parameters and (possibly) the array. I keep getting AccessViolationException - attempted to read or write protected memory

My goal is to call extraPutty API methods. I am able to call **Connexion**, but unable to call **Connexion_F**.

http://www.extraputty.com/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: Can't you use `ref` or `out`? (Depending on whether `method_2` expects values in `&param4` and `&param5`).

Comment: Why are you using `byte` for `param3` in `mapped_method_1` instead of `Boolean` or `bool`?

Comment: I found that in a tutorial. I am not C/C++/C# developer myself (I do java). It worked so I left it. I guess its because C has no problems representing numbers as boolean.

Comment: You need to use ref keyword for pointer parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
[DllImport("my_library.dll", EntryPoint = "method_2")]
static extern int mapped_method_2([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string param1, 
UInt32 param2, bool param3, 
ref bool param4,  ref long param5,
ref char[] param6);
```

Comment: Well, I still cannot call the connexion method form extraputty api without getting AccessViolationException, but googling around suggests, that your soulution is likely to be correct.

Comment: To solve your AccessViolationException you have to put the complete stack. It may be because you are trying to pass a variable by ref to the function which is being used or is protected. Or may be type memory representation between C and C#

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
[DllImport("my_library.dll", EntryPoint = "method_2")]
static extern int mapped_method_2(string param1, UInt32 param2, byte param3, byte* param4, UInt32 param2, string param6)
```